# Why is an uncountable set with the discrete topology not separable?

Tags: general-topology

I saw a proof on proofwiki but couldn't understand it. I only know the bare basics of topology (closed, open, limit points, neighbourhoods). Is there a simple proof for this?

Comment: In the discrete topology every subset is its own closure (this property characterizes the discrete topology).

Comment: Why not give a link to the proof you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we have an uncountable discrete space. If you have a discrete topological space, every subset is closed and open, so the closure of a subset is itself. So if you have a dense subset, then it must be the whole space, but the space is uncountable. (I am going off of the definition: a space is separable iff it has a countable dense subset).