# Why the metric space $(\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R}^d),\delta_{lu})$ is not separable?

Tags: metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of all cadlag functions $\mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$.  Consider the  *local uniform* topology
$$
\delta_{lu}(\alpha,\beta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\,(1\wedge||\alpha-\beta||_n)
$$
where $||\alpha||_t=\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|\alpha(s)|$. In Chapter VI of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540439323) it is said that $(\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R}^d),\delta_{lu})$ is not separable because the family $\{\alpha_s=1_{[s,\infty)}(t)|s\in[0,1)\}$ is uncountable but $\delta_{lu}(\alpha_s,\alpha_{s^{\prime}})=1/2$ for all $s\neq s^{\prime}$. Can someone explain to me why?
I now that separability of a space $X$ means the existence of a countable subset $S$ such that $\overline{S}=X$. Why the aforementioned example exclude the existence of such a countable subset?

**Addendum**

thanks to a comment I know that the solution comes from
this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067517/complete-proof-of-non-separability-of-d-space) and this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983187/why-is-an-uncountable-set-with-the-discrete-topology-not-separable).